# Strange Javascript behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I've the following code on my page, and after pagereload it works fine, but without reload this script won't work as intended.

1st use: works pretty good
2nd use: why is it jumping over 1 class?
3rd use: it is jumping over 2 classes

How to refresh script with out page-reload or what do I need to do?

```
$(document).ready(function(){  

 $('.partImg').each(function(){
        $(this).click(function(){
            $("#hideMod, #visMod, #nextP, #closeP, #prevP").fadeIn(400);
            $(this).next().addClass("ASert");
            var AV = $(".ASert").text();
            $('#visMod').html("<img src='" + AV + "'/>");

            $("#nextP").click(function(){
                if ($('.hidePart:last').hasClass("ASert") ) {
                    $('.hidePart:first').addClass("ASert");
                    $('.ASert').last().removeClass("ASert");
                } else {        
                    $('.ASert').next().next().addClass("ASert");
                    $('.ASert').first().removeClass("ASert");
                }
                var AV = $(".ASert").text();
                $('#visMod').html("<img src='" + AV + "'/>");
            });

            $("#prevP").click(function(){
                if ($('.hidePart:first').hasClass("ASert") ) {
                    $('.hidePart:last').addClass("ASert");
                    $('.ASert').first().removeClass("ASert");        
                } else {        
                    $('.ASert').prev().prev().addClass("ASert");
                    $('.ASert').last().removeClass("ASert");        
                }
                var AV = $(".ASert").text();
                $('#visMod').html("<img src='" + AV + "'/>");
            });        

            $("#closeP").click(function(){
                $("#hideMod, #visMod, #nextP, #closeP, #prevP").fadeOut(200);
                $(".ASert").removeClass("ASert");
            });
       });
    });
});
```

http://istyle.kz/test/index.php?id=32 here you can view point of question.

1. Click on any image and try to prev/next
2. Close lightbox
3. Click again on image and try to prev/next

Comment: Your question is very hard to understand. 1) Big wall o' text without any attempt to indent it so it's readable 2) Little/no description of the actual problem 3) No info on how to reproduce the problem.

Comment: you should try to indent your code, so other people can read it. you might try replacing all the .click(function() {...}) with .on('click', function() {...})

i think you would have to include the html for anyone to understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Ive made an attempt to indent your code properly, but I doubt you'll get any decent answers due to the vagueness of the question and the lack of info required to repoduce your problem.

Comment: As @Ringo mentioned , I guess that the issue is with the `click` method. Your clicks are not `unbind`ing

Comment: i've just recently replace .click(function() {...}) with .on('click', function() {...}) but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: i've updated 1st post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty common problem with javascript. Inside click handler you are binding another click handler. If this is necessary, unbinding should be performed somewhere.

However, it doesn't seem to be necessary. So, I would suggest refactoring the code this way:

```
$(function(){
    $("#nextP").on("click", function(){
        //...
    });
    $("#prevP").on("click", function(){
        //...
    });
    $("#closeP").on("click", function(){
        //...
    });
    $('.partImg').on( "click", function(){
        $("#hideMod, #visMod, #nextP, #closeP, #prevP").fadeIn(400);
        //...
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.